# UIBarButton Title Only Shows Periodically

Tags: ios, ios6, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm adding a UIToolbar to my UIViewController programmatically.

The problem I have is that when my view is created the buttons in the toolbar "DO" show but they do not show their title text.

If I wait for 10 - 20 seconds or sometimes even longer the titles will eventually show.

I tried calling setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout to force the UI yo update but it straight up doesnt work.

Am I doing something ridiculous? I can't for the life of me figure out why the title don't show immediately.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self= [super init];

    if (self) {
        UIView  *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        self.view=view;
        cellLoader = [UINib nibWithNibName:CellClassName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;

        self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                                                    self.view.frame.origin.y+44,
                                                                    self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                    self.view.frame.size.height-44)
                                                   style:UITableViewStylePlain];

        [self.tableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];
        [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];


        self.tableView.dataSource=self;
        self.tableView.delegate=self;
        //[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)];

        navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

        UILabel* lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-200,50,100,40)];
        [lbNavTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lbNavTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [lbNavTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        lbNavTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"",@"");
        navItem.titleView = lbNavTitle;

        naviBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
        naviBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;
        naviBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
        naviBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0);


        toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 44)];

        toolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;
        NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];





         button1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithTitle:@"Button 1 text"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                               action:@selector(buttononepressed:)];
        [buttons addObject: button1];

        UIBarButtonItem *spacer1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];

        [buttons addObject:spacer1];

        button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                            initWithTitle:@"Button 2 text"
                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                            action:@selector(button2pressed:)];
        [buttons addObject:button2];




        [toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];



            [self.view addSubview:toolBar];


            [naviBar setNeedsDisplay];
            [toolbar setNeedsDisplay];
            [self.view setNeedsDisplay];







    }

    return self;

}
```

Comment: why the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` ? This must be what causes the delay

Comment: That was just some silly act of code desperation. I've removed it now. The problem persists.

Comment: and the code you're providing is your `UIViewController` ?

Comment: `[buttons button2];`  <-- is this a copy paste error?  I believe you want addObject:

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if this is your viewController, you don't want to create all the view hierarchy in the init method, instead, use the `viewDidLoad` method. (and you don't have to set `self.view` yourself, default implementation in `UIViewController` does that for you)

Also, you're creating a `UINavigationBar` AND a `UIToolBar`, setting same frames for both when you just add the toolbar as subview... (I'll consider this `UINavigationBar` junk code too)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    cellLoader = [UINib nibWithNibName:CellClassName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;

    self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                                                      self.view.frame.origin.y+44,
                                                                    self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                    self.view.frame.size.height-44)
                                                   style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;

    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 44)];
    toolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;



    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 1 text"
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                 action:@selector(buttononepressed:)];    
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 2 text"
                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                action:@selector(button2pressed:)];



    // using Objective-C litterals you shorter code than using NSMutableArray !
    [toolbar setItems:@[button1, spacer1, button2] animated:NO];



    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];


  }

}
```

Normally, that's all you need (no call to `setNeedsDisplay`, these are done automatically when adding subviews)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I moved my view building code to viewDidLoad but the problem is there. The text on the barButtonItems only show up after an arbitrary amount of time. It's very very strange.

Comment: The problem was I was creating my UIViewController on a background thread

Comment: Another `dispatch_async` ? these are not needed for UI code :)

Comment: Almost! I had the creation call in an NSOperation. Lesson well learned!